# what does '#@' means in oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have oracle query below

```
SELECT   
tr.hetid,   
tr.hfncd,   
tr.op_code,   
tr.bps_batch_seq,   
substr(op_code, -3) add_del_flag,   
tr.ack_msg,   
'#@' seg_data   
from table_name   
where <condition>
```

I don't understand, what '#@' means in the query

Comment: It's just a constant literal string.

Comment: Just run the query and see what happens. If every the column value in every row is literally `#@`, chances are it is indeed a literal.

Comment: @Marco - it's putting that [text literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) into every row in the result set (as [a column expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions005.htm#SQLRF20043)); it's nothing to do with any data already in the table.

Comment: @AlexPoole That's what I said, isn't it? I just wanted to point out, that the meaning of it could be inferred by just running the query and seeing what comes out of it, without the help of SO.

Comment: @Marco - I see, so 'if every column value in every row' was referring to the result set not the table data? Misinterpreted that, sorry. The 'If ...' and 'chances are' parts are confusing though, since there is no 'if' about it *8-)

Comment: we're calling that lost in translation if one or more parties of a conversation don't have the same native tongue :)

Comment: Do you mean that this value '#@'will go to this field name==> seg_data   ?

Answer (score 0):

`'#@'` is a simple [text literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617)
Just like other text literals.

```
SELECT 
    'some name' As name,
    'Some text' as Text,
    'This is some string' As String,
    '#@' As seg_data   
FROM dual

NAME      TEXT      STRING              SE
--------- --------- ------------------- --
some name Some text This is some string #@
```